# DisallowedHost error not going away when adding IP address to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, pip

If I set ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] I am able to make a succesfull call, however this seems dangerous and counterintuitive.

When I set ALLOWED_HOSTS to the recommended string, it fails. How to fix this?

Comment: Recommended string? Are you setting it to `"some string"` or `["some string"]`?

Comment: ["some string"]

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged your post with AWS, I assume the host in question is an AWS EC2 instance.  If so, try put in your EC2 private IP or your full domain instead, like:

```
['ip-XX-XX-XX-XX.XX-XXX-X.compute.internal']
  OR
['.yourdomain.com']
```

The preceding `.` in your domain name represents a wildcard, as described in Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

Comment: Even when I try to run on local host I get the error, I then do ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["http://127.0.0.1:8000"] and no success

Comment: For local host, have you tried `['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']`?

Comment: No dice. I'm using conda instead of just pip to instal django, could the error stem from there?

Comment: I've rarely used Conda so I don't have much insight here.  One other thing I would check is to make sure there isn't other conflicting settings of ALLOWED_HOST configured elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this and found the reason. There were 2 different tabs which were running server. For test reasons I just started server in another tab. Django doesn't warn in the second tab. So your requests are most probably falling to the another tab running the server.